# Formula for Finding Moving Number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to pay a certain amount of money, but that certain amount changes because of the various fees that are charged, which are dependent upon the money paid.  I need to calculate about a hundred of these, so a formula for automation would be nice. Goal Seeker gets me there, so does guessing and checking, but it is cumbersome for the volume I have to do.

Here is the sample I have: Total amount on hand is $1,010.  In other words, the goal is to figure out what amount I have to start with so that I am only paying out $1,010, not a penny more.  Three fees need to be paid out of this $1,010.  The first fee is 3% of the first $500 (so, in my example, $15 because the amount to be paid will be more than $500).  The second fee is 1.5% of the remaining amount (so, in my example, ($1,010 - $500) x .015).  The third fee is a flat $5.  Using Goal Seeker and/or Guess & Check, I know that the amount I have to pay ("x" in my example) is $982.76.  Therefore, working backwards, adding $982.76 + $15 + $7.24 + $5 = $1,010.  I would really like to have a formula that I can use to figure all of this out.  Suggestions, please?  Thank you!

Comment: This has been asked in recent past, !!

Answer (score 0):

On hand values in column A.

Fees:

```
=IF(A2>500,500*0.03+((A2-500)*0.015)+5,A2*0.03+5)
```

Amount before fees:

```
=A2-B2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  The issue with this one is that the "otherwise" part of the formula is not contingent upon A2, it is contingent upon the missing number, x.  For the example, the 2nd Fee is not contingent upon $1,010, it is contingent upon how much is to be declared so that everything added up is $1,010.  The formula proposed is $0.41 off.